# Function()() mutiple calling to access child functions in javascript

Tags: javascript, function

```js
var obj = {
  bar: function() {
    var x = (() => this);
    return x;
  }
};

// Call bar as a method of obj, setting its this to obj
// Assign a reference to the returned function to fn
var fn = obj.bar();

// Call fn without setting this, would normally default
// to the global object or undefined in strict mode
console.log(fn() === obj); // true

// But caution if you reference the method of obj without calling it
var fn2 = obj.bar;
// Calling the arrow function's this from inside the bar method()
// will now return window, because it follows the this from fn2.
console.log(fn2()() == window); // true
```

My question is that at last line `fn2()()` is called but with two sets of  closing bracket` which executes the child function. But I searched along web and did not got this double or triple, etc. type of function call anywhere.

So I want ask which part of JavaScript have this topic and how actually it works behind the scene?

Comment: `fn2()` returns another function. So you need a second set of `()` to call that other function.

Comment: In `var fn = obj.bar(); fn()` you’re also making two calls, just split up into two separate expressions.